# Advanced Core Animation/OpenGLES Tutorial Request

Tags: ios, animation

I'm looking to develop some more advance image manipulation routines than what is capable with the core `CGAffineTransform` API. Specifically I'm attempting to animate images so that they look like jiggling jello, or rubber under the weight of a bowling ball etc...

What type of tutorials would I benefit from following?

Answer (score 8):

I was hoping you were going to get a few good answers to this question as I am also interested myself. In the interest of sharing some resources, here is a good one that I came across lately:

http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1

http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-2

http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-3

http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4

Cheers,
Rog